# LXC + Ubuntu 18.04: "Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver" when trying to create a new container

Tags: 18.04, lxc, container

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server and trying to setup some containers but I'm getting the keyserver error:

```
> lxc-create -n test -t download
Setting up the GPG keyring
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver
lxc-create: test: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1566 Failed to create container from template
Error creating container test
```

Everything seems to work fine if I run with --no-validate but that's not what I would like to do long term, any ideas?

Btw. forgot to mention - I'm not behind any firewall or proxy that is blocking the access.

Edit: @Simos - the 'kde' was my fault when i copied the console output. The container i was creating was named kde, but i changed the name when copying the output here to 'test' just missed one spot. Nonetheless i like lxc and i've setup multiple containers to do some stuff i wanted just always had to skip validation which i don't like.

So the question remains - any pointers in how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For those of you willing to give --no-validate a try the syntax is

```
lxc-create -n test -t download -- --no-validate
```

Answer (score 0):

the following command could help:

```
lxc-create -n test -t download -- --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
```

Comment: Hello there, please include more details to your answer.